# Access file:/// images in Cordova

Tags: file, cordova, filereader

How can I do this? When I try to do something like this (from the Phonegap docs):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("file:///test.png", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);
    readAsText(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as text");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

It says there's an encoding error (code 5: `ENCODING_ERR`).  I know that the URI points to the right place.  How can I access the `file:///` images?

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: See my edit.  Code 5: `ENCODING_ERR`.

Comment: Might be because you need to remove 'file:///', specify only the filename - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858982/cordova-ionic-ngcordova-ios-or-iphone-file-read-error-code-5-encoding-err/27523006#27523006

Comment: I tried that and it gave me a not found error.

Comment: What platform(s) are you using?

Comment: iOS.  I'm getting the image URL through the Cordova contacts plugin.